# NameError in bottlenose API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, bottlenose

I installed bottlenose and tried this sample code:

```
import bottlenose
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG)
response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="0596520999", ResponseGroup="Images",
```

I put in all my keys but I always getting a `NameError` saying `amazon is not defined`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: hi @sidni, what do you have when you do `dir(bottlenose)`?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your `NameError` problem. Have you already ran `$ pip install bottlenose` with no errors? It looks correct to me provided you gave it valid keys.

Comment: this is the error: https://postimg.org/image/92d9ibww5/                 #the stuff i blanked out is all my keys. sorry for the mess

Comment: realised i did not ass str on my keys